# Getting Map is not defined in wso2 script tag

Tags: javascript, wso2, javascript-objects, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-integrator

When I create a map like below

```
var detailsMap = new Map();
```

I'm getting below exception.

```
ScriptMediator The script engine returned an error executing the
inlined js script function mediate
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException:
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Map" is not
defined. (<Unknown Source>#4) in <Unknown Source> at line number 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```js
var detailsMap = new java.util.HashMap();
```

**Update**

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
   var log = mc.getServiceLog();
   var detailsMap = new java.util.HashMap();
   detailsMap.put("123", "test value");
   log.info("Map value: " + detailsMap.get("123"));
]]>
</script>
```

Comment: In script tag can we write java code? i initialized map as {}, but not able to set values in to that map. Can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: @Praveenkumar yes the underline javascript engine allows you to use Java capabilities too.

Comment: okay. I tried but didn't get expected data.
I wrote below lines but the map value printing as empty in the log.
var mapTest = new java.util.HashMap();
mapTest.put(1,"hello");
mc.setProperty("mapTest-variable",mapTest);
Can you please tell me what mistake i did in this.

Comment: @Praveenkumar you can't assign a Map object to a property,so do `mc.setProperty("mapTestParam",mapTest.get(1));` The example I provided is a working example.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. I did it by initializing map with {} and I made keys are of type string, then it worked.